# Hibernate 6.2.5 Final, Audit Table Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

I have shifted form **hibernate5** to **hibernate6**, in this migration I have find out one major issue of saving `uuid` in `db`. For that in **H5** we had `@Type(type="uuid-char")`, in **h6** I replace with `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)` and it worked. But the issue is the AuditTable.. Audit table is giving me incorrect string excpetion..

This is the My Entity Class

```
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditTable;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;
import sg.customs.ntp.rsrf.commonservice.base.model.BaseModel;

import java.util.UUID;

@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_sample", schema = "sample_schema", catalog = "sample_schema")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Audited
@AuditTable(value = "tbl_sample_audit", schema = "sample_schema", catalog = "sample_schema")
public class SampleModel extends BaseModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SampleId")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
    private UUID sampleId = UUID.randomUUID();
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CompanyId")
    private CompanyModel company;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserId")
    private UserModel user;

    @Column(name = "Email", length = 300)
    private String email;

}
`
```

While jpa persist to the db I am getting this error...

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x91\xF5V\xA5F...' for column 'SampleId' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:275)
    ... 136 more
```

Comment: Since UUID class is not a managed type I would expect/advise to use String type `private String sampleId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

Comment: This is feasible for small test case but for somthing large it not feasible, in hibernate5 (@Type(type="uuid-char") was working for both tables and auditTables.. so in hibernate6 this @Type is not present. So  @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR) works very well for tables, but for audit tables dont know how to configure, If you can provide a direct soultion for that.

Comment: @MahenderKumar did you resolve the issue by now? I'm facing the same problem at this moment

Comment: Seems I could fix it by using custom AttributeConverter with autoApply = true, but curious about your fix

Comment: I removed the @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR) annoation and used below property and it worked at that time

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type.preferred_uuid_jdbc_type=VARCHAR`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this issue with custom attribute converter. I'm not sure why h6  envers is ignoring the @JdbcType annotation but this should work the same way:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UuidConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final UUID attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbData)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return UUID.fromString(dbData);
        }
    }

}
```